# Troubleshoot mstsc /span from Windows XP to Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, rdp, mstsc, graphics

At work, I often use the "mstsc" command to use the Microsoft Terminal Services Client and remote to another machine.  In my case, I'm using Windows XP (call this **box 1**) to connect to a Windows Server 2008 box (call this **box 2**).  I'd like to be able to span RDP across multiple monitors using "mstsc /span", but this does not work for me.  ***How can I troubleshoot or fix this?***  Often times people answer telling how it should work, but I'd prefer if you can describe how to troubleshoot my issue, or what to look for.

**My investigation so far:**

I read in the link below, that dual monitors is only possible when using RDP6.  I'm assuming this has something to do with the graphics card.  Does **box 1** or **box 2** need RDP6?  And how would I check?

http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/20062-dual-monitor-rdp-xp-computer.html

## EDIT #1:

After downloading the *.exe file from below, I got this message:

***Post Mortem Note:*** *I used Google Chrome, not Internet Explorer to click the link.*

[image]

So then I downloaded this:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20888

## EDIT #2:

After clicking the link in Internet Explorer, I get this after clicking "Install".

***Post Mortem Note:*** *I had Internet Explorer still open from the previous install to download Windows Genuine Advantage.  Apparently, you must close the Internet Explorer browser and click the original link again.  Then you won't get the Windows exception throwing this dialog.*

[image]

## EDIT #3:

[image]

[image]

***Apparently I had this update already.***

[image]

Comment: Followed these instructions: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_install/this-version-microsoft-genuine-advantage-no-longer/0fb38aef-17c8-40e2-b98d-9b77451b5c78

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an update, as such: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21075

This will install the required version of remote desktop.

And [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925876) link from Microsoft explains the update in more detail.

Comment: Okay, I had to click that link using Internet Explorer.  Using Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox doesn't work and gives the dialog in my EDIT #1 telling me that I need to validate Windows.  However, even when clicking it in IE, I get the screen shot in my second EDIT.

Comment: I had to close all IE browsers in Windows XP after it installed Windows Genuine Advantage.  Otherwise it'll throw the debug dialog in EDIT #2.  Now I get the actual download.  See EDIT #3 for those screen shots.

Comment: any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm...I got nothing unfortunately.

Comment: @MacGyver Oh, are both monitors the exact same resolution? That's a mentioned requirement.

Comment: Currently, they are not.  I can test that when I can get a different monitor at work.

Comment: Now I have two large monitors with the same resolution.  Your plan worked!!